# Why is AES_DECRYPT returning null?

Tags: mysql, aes

I've found similar questions, but no clear answer for this question. I have this table:

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 

CREATE TABLE testTable
(
firstName binary(32) not null,
lastName binary(32) not null
/* Other non-binary fields omitted */
)
engine=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This statement executes just fine:

```
INSERT INTO testTable (firstName) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('Testname', 'test'));
```

But, this returns NULL:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(firstName, 'test') FROM testTable;
```

Why does this return NULL?

Fwiw, this returns "testValue" as expected:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('testValue','thekey'), 'thekey');
```

Comment: @owlstead I did. It's in both the INSERT and SELECT statements. The field I'm selecting is `firstName` from the table `testTable`.

Comment: Oh, that was you, my mistake, thanks for reporting that back :) You can accept your own answer after a whilte

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is that the columns are `binary` when they should be `varbinary`. [This article](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/) explains it:

> Because if AES_DECRYPT() detects invalid data or **incorrect
>   padding**, it will return NULL.

With `binary` column types being fixed length, the length of the input value must be known to ensure correct padding. For unknown length values, use `varbinary` to avoid issues with incorrect padding resulting from differing value lengths.

Comment: Hey, I was just experimenting with AES functions, and i had set my `email_id` field to `varbinary(30)`. And for an email of length>16, the  `AES_ENCRYPT` output probably had a length of 30 + padding. And when I used AES_DECRYPT on my records, that particular record was showing null, after I altered `email_id`'s size to `varbinary(50)`

So did it turn to NULL on AES_DECRYPT because of what you're saying or because I changed the size of `email_id` to 50?

Answer (score 0):

When you insert binary data into a VARCHAR field there are some binary characters that a VARCHAR can't handle and they will mess up in the inserted value. And then the inserted value will not be the same when you retrieve it.
1.select hex(aes_encrypt(file,'key'));
2.select aes_decrypt(unhex(file),'key');

Answer (score 0):

Check if type of your field is blob instead binary(32)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try different values other than 'Testname'? 
Do other values work?

I ask because I had a situation while testing 2 test credit card numbers where one decrypted fine and the other returned null.

The answer was to hex and unhex as suggested by "abhinai raj"

Comment: You don't seem to be supplying a new answer here