# Getting null for every email in my sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

I'm working with another programmer with a very long list of emails. He sent them to me encrypted, and said I simply need to use aes_decrypt(email, 'passwordsalt') to get them.

I used:

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase.emails;
```

to confirm that i could see the emails (encrypted) in a table. I could. The table consists of three columns: id,email,blank.
However, when I used:

```
SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(email,'passwordsalt') AS email, blank FROM mydatabase.emails;
```

In the column for email all I got was null values. Does anyone know if there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: First question is, is the password salt really "passwordsalt" for each email, or did you maybe misunderstand, and there is a column named "passwordsalt"?  If so, you'd change your query to SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(email,passwordsalt) AS email, blank FROM mydatabase.emails;  -- No single quotes around "passwordsalt".  If the salt really IS the same on all, well, that's not very secure...

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224515/why-is-aes-decrypt-returning-null