# MySQL AES_DECRYPT returns NULL

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I have a MySQL issue.

I want to decrypt a blob with AES_DECRYPT and try it in phpMyAdmin with a query

```
SELECT key_value ,AES_DECRYPT(key_value,'crypt_key')FROM `ps_keymanager` WHERE `id_keymanager`=1497
```

the query works, but it returned me NULL
and not the decrypted value :(

Answer (score 1):

Try casting

```
   SELECT key_value , CAST (AES_DECRYPT(key_value,'crypt_key')AS CHAR(50))
FROM `ps_keymanager` WHERE `id_keymanager`=1497
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your replay, i try it but it returned also null :(.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224515/why-is-aes-decrypt-returning-null

Comment: Yes ,Thanks for your help i found this post before but don´t know what i have to do in my case

Comment: what datatype does the key_value in your ps_keymanager table have?

Comment: Hi Kunda the key_value is a blob what you think?

Comment: Try to change it to varbinary

Comment: hi how can i do this in a simple query? ALTER TABLE ps_keymanager MODIFY key_value VARBINARY. Dont work for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106406/discussion-between-s-kunda-and-devil089).

Comment: using CAST solved my problem, my datatype of the encrypted value in the database was varbinary(255), using CAST AS CHAR(255) solved my problem.