# Getting null in JSON response

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to encrypt the data and fetch it after decryption. I am using

```
AES_ENCRYPT and  AES_DECRYPT functions of MYSQL
```

I tried a lot to point out the mistake but I could not understand why I am getting null response.please tell me where am i going wrong

Here is my code

```
<?php
//Turn off all error reporting
//error_reporting(0);
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");

error_reporting(E_ALL);



 if(($_GET['action'])&&($_GET['username'])&&($_GET['key'])) {

$select = $_GET['action'];
$username =$_GET['username']; //no default
$key= $_GET['key'];
if($key=='dYrtr3GGPVuhSMvm'){
if($select=='select'){
        /* connect to the db */
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','')or die("Couldn't connect to database!");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'easy_sign') or die ("Couldn't find database");

 $key="x1y2z3";

$query ="SELECT *, AES_DECRYPT(path, '$key') AS decrypted_path, AES_DECRYPT(filename, '$key') AS decrypted_name FROM origin WHERE username ='$username' ";



$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($numrows!==0)
{
$post = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$post['path'] = $row['decrypted_path'];
 $post['filename'] = $row['decrypted_name'];
 $post['username'] = $row['username'];
 $post['date'] = $row['date'];
 }

 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($post); 


     }
    }
   }
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: What is the output ? Is it `null` or the values of `path` and `filename` is null.

Comment: {"path":null,"filename":null,"username":"ali","date":"11\/11\/2016"} this is the out put

Comment: what is the data type of path and filename ?

Comment: you mean in database?

Comment: I mean data type of fields `path` and `filename`, what are they ?

Comment: it is varbinary for both

Comment: See answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022928/mysql-aes-decrypt-returns-null, try `CAST`.

Comment: how to use cast to decrypt two key values